# Unable to Rebase onto Master Branch

Tags: git, msysgit

I have two branches: `master` and `experimental`. I'd like to rebase the changes I've made in experimental onto master. But whenever I attempt to do so with, `git rebase master experimental`, I get: `Current branch experimental is up to date.` Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the experimental branch is already a descendant of the master branch.  If you want the commits from experimental branch on master you need to merge it.  Since you rebased it will be a fast-forward commit that doesn't result in a merge commit (unless you specify --no-ff):

```
git checkout master && git merge experimental
```